# Wrong response headers Content-type .NET core 3

Tags: .net-core, controller, http-headers

I'm trying to return list of object, but controller set response headers Content-type as text/plain and I get 500 error. I tried to return single object of this list (list is not empty), but problem was same. Then I tried to return simple object (LoginModelDto) and then response headers Content-type was set correct (application/json) and controller returned 200 OK. I do not understand, why .net core set response headers Content-type incorrectly for Table object.

_tableService.getData(data) is returning IEnumerable, Table class is generated by EF.

This is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost("Endpoint")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public IActionResult GetData([FromBody]Object data)
    {
        var id = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("Id", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (id != null)
        {
            var res = _tableService.getData(data).ToList();
            //Table tbl = res.First();
            //LoginModelDto lgn = new LoginModelDto
            //{
            //    Email = "aaa",
            //    Password = "bbb"
            //};
            return Ok(res);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Identity not found" });
        }
```

this is my Table object structure:

```
    public int [name] { get; set; }
    public int [name] { get; set; }
    public int [name] { get; set; }
    public int [name] { get; set; }
    public int [name] { get; set; }
    public bool [name] { get; set; }
    public DateTime [name] { get; set; }
    public DateTime? [name] { get; set; }

    public virtual Obj [objname] { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OtherObj> [otherObjName] { get; set; }
```

Comment: share your code from `getData()` service

Comment: _tableService.getData() returning IEnumerable<Table>. Table is context class generated by Entity Framework. Returned IEnumerable is not empty.